# DataInputStream.readUTF is not receiving any string from Node.js Server

Tags: android, node.js

Today I was writing an app (Android) that received strings from a server in Node.js. The socket connection is fine, I can send from Android to Server just fine, but when it comes to receiving from Server, readUTF() is stuck at reading. Here's the Android code to send and receive:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("10.13.37.129",1337);
                            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                            jsonObject.put("data", "Tristen");
                            dataOutputStream.writeUTF(jsonObject.toString());
                            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                            System.out.println("Receiving");
                            final byte[] buffer = {};
                            dataInputStream.read(buffer);
                            string = new String(buffer);
                            System.out.println("Received");
                            Runnable runnable1 = new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    System.out.println("This is the string: " + string);
                                    System.out.println("This is the buffer: " + buffer.length);
                                    System.out.println("This is the buffer.ToString(): " + buffer.toString());
                                    textView.setText(string);
                                }
                            };
                            runOnUiThread(runnable1);
```

And this is the server code to send the string:

```
// Add a 'data' event handler to this instance of socket
clientSocket.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('DATA: ' + data);
    clientSocket.write('Hello\n');
    clientSocket.write('World\n');
});
```

Can anyone see what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readUTF()` is for reading strings written by `DataOutputStream.writeUTF().`. Nothing else. Use `read(),` `BufferedReader.readLine(),` etc.

Comment: Thanks man, I realized this before so I've already changed it. But yours is the correct answer for future reference on this post